# How to Update A Newly Inserted Record in MySQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers

I want to import a list of names in a spreadsheet into a table. For some reason, the names in the spreadsheet always arrive in a messed up way. - Some have trailing spaces, while some have a period at the end. I have the code to clean up all of these inconsistencies. The problem is getting everything to work via triggers.  I created two tables:

1. tblemployeesimported
2. tblemployees

I created an After Insert trigger on the first table (tblemployeesimported) to append every new record into the second table. Some cleaning is done in this first trigger and it works as expected. The problem is there are more operations that I want to perform on the imported data and I can't do all of it via the first trigger because it is an INSERT INTO statement.

I then created a Before Insert trigger on the second table (tblemployees) so that I can modify one of the fields. But I keep getting an error that the table is already being used . This is despite the fact that this second trigger is before insert and not after insert or before/after update.

The specific error message is:

> ERROR 1442: 1442: Can't update table 'tblemployees' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
> SQL Statement:

I have created a fiddle link of the tables, the triggers and a sample insert statement as well.

[DB Fiddle of all the code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9637fb6f1f7b782096e2ba146797d212)

The code is also below:

Create the first table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblemployeesimported` (
  `rwID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `EmpNameImported` varchar(85) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rwID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Create the second table:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblemployees` (
  `rwID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `EmpNameImported` varchar(85) DEFAULT NULL,
  `EmpNameGood` varchar(85) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`rwID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Trigger of first table (tblemployeesimported):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `cleanimportednames` AFTER INSERT
    ON `tblemployeesimported`
    FOR EACH ROW 
    
    BEGIN

INSERT INTO
     `tblemployees`(EmpNameImported, EmpNameGood)

SELECT 
`tblemployeesimported`.`EmpNameImported`, 
If(
        
        Right(Trim(`tblemployeesimported`.`EmpNameImported`), 1) = '.', 
        
        Substring(Trim(`tblemployeesimported`.`EmpNameImported`), 1, Char_Length(Trim(`tblemployeesimported`.`EmpNameImported`)) - 1) , 
        
        Substring(Trim(`tblemployeesimported`.`EmpNameImported`), 1, Char_Length(Trim(`tblemployeesimported`.`EmpNameImported`)))

        )

FROM `tblemployeesimported`

WHERE rwID = new.rwID;

    END
```

Trigger of second table (tblemployees):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `tblemployees_Trigger_INSERT` BEFORE INSERT
    ON `tblemployees`
    FOR EACH ROW 
    
    BEGIN
    
UPDATE `tblemployees`
SET new.EmpNameGood = LOWER(EmpNameGood);


    END
```

Sample data entry into first table (tblemployeesimported):

```
INSERT INTO `tblemployeesimported` (`EmpNameImported`) VALUES ('John Adam SMITH');
```

I then get the error in DB Fiddle as well:

> Can't update table 'tblemployees' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

How can I solve this? There are several operations that I still want to perform on the imported data. - That's why I need a second trigger. I have tried using a Stored Procedure but I get the same error.

**Update**

@Akina , this is the code for the before insert trigger in workbench. It's causing Error 1054: Unknown Column

```
CREATE DEFINER=`professorxavier`@`localhost` TRIGGER `empnamesdb`.`cleaning2` BEFORE INSERT
    ON `empnamesdb`.`tblemployees`
    FOR EACH ROW 
    
BEGIN
    
SET new.EmpNameGood = LOWER(EmpNameGood)

END
```

**Update 2:** Screenshot showing that the correct field name is used in the trigger of the second table. I've underlined the field names both in the Navigation Pane and in the trigger.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `tblemployees_Trigger_INSERT` trigger is incorrect. You must not update the table but alter the value to be inserted.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `tblemployees_Trigger_INSERT` 
BEFORE INSERT ON `tblemployees`
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.EmpNameGood = LOWER(NEW.EmpNameGood);
```

Also you "clearing" code is too complex and may be simplified to `` TRIM(TRAILING '.' FROM TRIM(`tblemployeesimported`.`EmpNameImported`)) ``.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=ae48a439d0314bf27b3b4d56fec60355)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the second trigger without phrasing it as an update query. It works in DB Fiddle but not in Workbench. When I insert data into the 1st table,  I get an error: ERROR 1054: 1054: Unknown column 'EmpNameGood' in 'field list'

Comment: I've 'edited' the question to include the code for the second trigger as it is in Workbench.

Comment: @TheoFitchner Check correct name for the column in `empnamesdb.tblemployees` table.

Comment: I've checked again. I'm using the correct field name. If I delete the second trigger, the first trigger works as intended - the new entry is appended to the second table. I've updated the question to include a screenshot from Workbench to show that the correct field name is being used.

Comment: Apologies. I just looked at your own fiddle again and I realised that I didn't add the 'new' qualifier after the equals sign. What I typed was SET new.EmpNameGood = LOWER(EmpNameGood) while it shoudl be SET new.EmpNameGood = LOWER(new.EmpNameGood). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for simplifying the TRIM function. Much appreciated.